# Convert NSString to few NSIntegers

Tags: xcode, nsstring, int, valueconverter

I have getting data from plist to NSString, in result I see something like this "{{1848,594},{154,176}}". What is the best way to convert every single number to separate NSInteger?

NSString *frame = [myPlistKey objectForKey:@"frame"];

How to convert frame to 4 separate integers?

Comment: If you get an array of strings or whatever, use `for` loop.

Comment: Can you get example of code or link on tutorial?

Comment: Im not sure if you get an array or just weird one string looks like you posted {{1848,594},{154,176}}.

Comment: What created the plist? What did it use to create that string? It looks like the result of `NSStringFromRect()` in which case you should use `NSRectFromString()` to convert it back to an `NSRect`.

Comment: You are right! CGRectFromString()it working! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, it looks like you are trying to parse the string representation of an `NSRect`, in which case you can just use [`NSRectFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSRectFromString) from the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Since you are not much specific, I will try to cover your situation. If i count with the fact you have `NSString *frame` filled with *{{1848,594},{154,176}}*:

```
    NSString *stringWithoutLeftBracket = [frame
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    NSString *stringWithoutRightBracket = [stringWithoutLeftBracket
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    NSArray *frameArray = [stringWithoutRightBracket componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
```

**Then you can access objects with indexes like:**

```
NSInteger integer = [[frameArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```

But also you could use a `for` loop like this:

```
for (NSInteger integer in frameArray) {

    // Do something
}
```

**In my opinion** you have a string made from rect, means you could convert it.

Comment: if add NSInteger integer = [[frameArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]; app crash with "unrecognized selector sent to instance " error